# Firefox extension automatic update feature not working

Tags: apache, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

following the tutorial [here](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/automatic-firefox-extension-updates/), I'm trying to implement the automatic update feature for Firefox addons. Using the guide, I've created the key pair for mccoy. 
Subsequently I've create my install.rdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
   <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
      <em:id>ext@xuldev.org</em:id>
      <em:name>tmp Extension</em:name>
      <em:type>2</em:type>
      <em:version>1.0</em:version>
      <em:updateURL>http://130.192.../update.rdf</em:updateURL>
      <em:updateKey>MIGfMA0GCSqGS...</em:updateKey>
      <em:targetApplication>
         <Description>
            <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
            <em:minVersion>4.0</em:minVersion>
            <em:maxVersion>30.*</em:maxVersion>
        </Description>
      </em:targetApplication>
   </Description>
</RDF>
```

Subsequently I've take the sha256 of my xpi file and I've created the update.rdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<r:RDF xmlns:r="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
<r:Description about="urn:mozilla:extension:myextension@ext@xuldev.org">
<updates>
<r:Seq>
<r:li>
<r:Description>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <targetApplication>
        <r:Description>
        <id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</id>
        <minVersion>4.0</minVersion>
        <maxVersion>30.*</maxVersion>
        <updateLink>http://130.192.../ext.xpi</updateLink>
        <updateHash>
            sha256:b3290c69a1...
        </updateHash>
        </r:Description>
    </targetApplication>
</r:Description>
</r:li>
</r:Seq>
</updates>
</r:Description>
</r:RDF>
```

Finally, I've configured the .htaccess on my site folder. Inserting the updateLink directly in the browser url, I find the files, but Firefox didn't update the extension. From console log, I see this:

```
addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Users\...ext@xuldev.org.xpi
addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Users\...ext@xuldev.org.xpi
addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on ext@xuldev.org version 1.0
addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for ext@xuldev.org did not contain an updates property
addons.manager  DEBUG   onUpdateFinished for ext@xuldev.org
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Not a solution, but an alternative. I remember having trouble with this a while back. As you've probably already seen on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility#Securing_Updates) you can host your addon on an https page and forgo hashes/keys/mccoy.

Comment: Thanks willlma, actually I've already seen the page but I wanted to follow the guide that I linked in the question. In your opinion, using https I would have fewer problems?

Comment: Yeah, I use https and it's a piece of cake. No hashes or anything, you just need an updaterdf file with the correct links and it works. If you have any problems getting it set up, ask another question and link to it in the comments here.

Comment: I've tried to follow your answer but I've a problem.....question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102824/firefox-extension-automatic-update-with-https-and-self-signed-certificates