# Firefox extension automatic update with HTTPS and self-signed certificates

Tags: apache, firefox, ssl, firefox-addon

after the suggestion of willlma to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037900/firefox-extension-automatic-update-feature-not-working), I'm trying to implement the automatic update feature for Firefox addons using HTTPS connections. I created the essential files and Firefox connects correctly to the server, but there is the follow error:

```
addons.update-checker   DEBUG   Requesting https://130.192..../update.rdf
130.192.... uses a security certificate not valid
certificate is not trusted because it is self signed
(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)
addons.update-checker   WARN    HTTP Request failed for an unknown reason
```

So, the error message is right, because I use a self signed certificate. I've tried to take free a certificate (for example from [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com)) but I don't have a domain. Do you have ideas to solve this situation?

Comment: you need to change a firefox setting in the about:config. Firefox introduced an annoying certificate checking recently

Comment: see http://blog.dob.sk/2014/07/23/firefox-31-self-signed-certificate-sec_error_ca_cert_invalid/

Comment: I had the same problem last Friday. I don't know why, for me, I had to set the value to "true" instead of "false" to make it work.

Comment: I toggle to false the security.use_mozillapkix_verification value but the problem doesn't solve for me

Comment: try true instead of false

Comment: I've tried with either values

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think self-signed certificates will work.